# Get sourceRect of a SwiftUI view for popover presentation in UIKit ViewController (via UIHostingController)

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uihostingcontroller

I'm using the following pattern:

- UIViewController
- that has UIHostingController as immediate child
- and of course the UIHostingController view added as subview of the main VC and anchoring to the edges

```
lazy var hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: EDWrapperView(exportDestinationVC: self))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addChild(hostingVC)
    self.view.addSubview(hostingVC.view)
    
    hostingVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    hostingVC.view.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
    
    self.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingVC.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingVC.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingVC.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingVC.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    configureNavigation()
    
    // Theme
    ThemeManager.shared.registerForThemeChanges(observer: self)
}
```

You can see that the SwiftUIView has a reference to the UIKitVC for calling functions (it kinda acts as a ViewModel).

In that very same UIViewController, I have a function that presents a popover, which requires a sourceView and a sourceRect.

```
func showActivityVC(sourceRect: CGRect) {
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    if let popOver = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
        popOver.sourceView = self.view! // Pass the UIVC view as sourceView
        popOver.sourceRect = sourceRect // Source rect has been computed by GeometryReader in SwiftUI. But its not exactly at the right position
    }
}
```

In the SwiftUIView, the button looks like this:

```
List {
    // Export button to iOS Share sset
    Section(header: Text("Export")) {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Button(action: {
                let insideFrame = geometry.frame(in: .global) // Get rect in the global view, which should be the same as the UIViewController view
                self.exportDestinationVC.presentIOSShareSheet(sourceRect: insideFrame)
            }, label: {
                HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    Text("Export")
                    Spacer()
                }
            })
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .position(x: geometry.size.width/2.0, y: geometry.size.height/2.0)
        }
    }
}
```

I use a `GeometryReader` to get the frame of the button in the global view, which **should** be the same as the UIViewController view.
It works, but not exactly, the popover does not point exactly where it should, there are some inaccuracies that comes from I don't know where.

**How can I get the exact sourceRect of the SwiftUI button inside the SwiftUI view?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler working solution, without needing a Coordinator. Meanwhile, it allows setting the title, font, and changing the color dynamically.

```
struct ButtonWithSourceView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var title: String
    var font: UIFont
    @Binding var color: UIColor
    var action: (UIButton) -> Void

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIButton {
        let uiButton = UIButton()
    
        uiButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        uiButton.titleLabel?.font = font
        uiButton.setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
        let uiAction = UIAction() { _ in
            action(uiButton)
        }
        uiButton.addAction(uiAction, for: .touchUpInside)
    
        return uiButton
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Self.Context) {
        uiView.setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue, geometry reader wasn't providing the correct y-value of the button and popover was flying away during an orientation change.

So, I did the following:
I created a UIViewRepresentable(say MyButton) instance for UIbutton, made a custom coordinator which held the UIbutton.

MyButton had a callback((UIButton) -> Void), when MyButton was tapped, I returned the UIbutton from the coordinator in that callback and set it as the sourceView for my popover, then presented it and it worked like a charm.

```
struct MyButton: UIViewRepresentable {
var action: (UIButton) -> Void

func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIButton {
    let uiButton = UIButton()
    context.coordinator.uiButton = uiButton
    context.coordinator.addTarget()
    
    return uiButton
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Self.Context) {}

class Coordinator: NSObject {
    var parent: MyButton
    var uiButton = UIButton()

    init(_ uiView: MyButton) {
        self.parent = uiView
    }
    
    func addTarget() {
        uiButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func tapped() {
        self.parent.action(uiButton)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind sharing the `UIViewRepresentable` code for the `UIButton`? Ideally with the callback. Would help a lot!

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is very kind, and helpful!